# Изменение селектора в обработчике событий

Tags: jquery, javascript, события

Как изменить селектор обработчика событий JQuery? Функция refreshThreshold () изменяет частоту тройных щелчков мыши.

Мой код не работает. Точнее, селектор не реагирует на переменную `thresholdVal`, словно запомнил в памяти дефолтное значение. Отсюда вытекает логичное решение перезагрузить обработчик.

**Поэтому 2 вопрос: Как можно его перезагрузить?**

Пытался использовать `.off()` и `.unbind()`, однако получаю ошибку, связанную со скриптом тройного клика:

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined"

`Tripleclick` взят отсюда: https://github.com/richadams/jquery-tripleclick

Мой код:

```
function refreshThreshold() {
    thresholdVal = $( "#trippleclickSlider" ).slider( "value" );
    console.log(thresholdVal);
}

var thresholdVal = 1000;
$("#div").on("tripleclick", { threshold: thresholdVal }, function()
{
//any process
});
```

Comment: это не предусмотрено создателем tripleclick. но вроде-бы можно вызвать teardown, в общем там ошибка в исходнике, просто забыли  определить data... http://plnkr.co/edit/N1Sjd4skCN74DEqtpZNJ?p=preview

Comment: Большое спасибо! А надо ведь было только заглянуть в скрипт!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из комментариев

> это не предусмотрено создателем `tripleclick`.
>
> но вроде-бы можно вызвать `teardown`, в общем там ошибка в исходнике, просто забыли определить
>
> data... plnkr.co/edit/N1Sjd4skCN74DEqtpZNJ?